# Eclipse ADT "undefined reference to (custom class)", but works fine in Xcode (using Cocos2dx)

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, xcode, cocos2d-x

I have a project that's fully functional in Xcode but not compiling in Eclipse ADT.  I have successfully compiled and run android applications in the past, but this is my first time to create a custom class.  To replicate the issue:

I create a new project, then add the following 2 files:

```
//Enemy.cpp
#include "Enemy.h"
USING_NS_CC;

bool Enemy::init()
{
    if(!Layer::init())
        return false;

    return true;
}

//Enemy.h
#ifndef __ColorMirror__Enemy__
#define __ColorMirror__Enemy__

#include <iostream>
#include "cocos2d.h"
USING_NS_CC;

class Enemy : public cocos2d::Layer{

public:
    CREATE_FUNC(Enemy);
    virtual bool init();
};

#endif
```

I am able to see them in Eclipse in the list of classes.

Then I create a new enemy in HelloWorldScene.cpp as follows:

```
Enemy *newEnemy = Enemy::create();
```

This compiles and runs as expected in Xcode, but when I run build_native.py I get the following errors:

```
jni/../../Classes/Enemy.h:19: error: undefined reference to 'Enemy::init()'
jni/../../Classes/Enemy.h:19: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for Enemy'
```

Checking in the jni/../../Classes file, I am able to find Enemy.h and Enemy.cpp.

I have seen several explanations for fixes in other versions of Eclipse, and the suggestion it's a linker error, but I haven't figured out how to fix it in ADT.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add Enemy.cpp to Androik.mk?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.  I might be doing it wrong, I opened Android.mk and under LOCAL_SRC_FILES I add:                     ../../Classes/Enemy.cpp \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not entirely sure which of these steps fixed the problem, and it may very well have been multiple issues, but here's what I did:

1) Added Enemy.cpp into Android.mk as follows:

```
Browse to game folder /proj.android/jni and open Android.mk
Open with TextEdit
Below the AppDelegate.cpp in LOCAL_SRC_FILES: added this:
    ../../Classes/Enemy.cpp \
Save
```

(still didn't work, so I took it out)

2) Changed workspace for Eclipse (which is specified on opening eclipse) and deleted old workspace

3) Downloaded and set up newest ADT package (Eclipse JUNO)

4) Upgraded Cocos2d-x from 3.1 to 3.2

(still didn't work)

5) Added Enemy.cpp to Android.mk again

Upon completing all those steps, everything works great and compiles as before.

Thanks to Wez Sie Tato for confirming that Enemy.cpp did in fact need to be added to Android.mk...  Based on some comments I've seen elsewhere, it appears that my ADT package may have gotten damaged somehow, in conjunction with not having the proper line in Android.mk

Comment: Well that worked all of once, now it's hanging on "Launching..." and copying at a ridiculously slow pace... 10 minutes to get to 88 megs, another 5 to get up to 93 megs, 500 left to go...